# How do you know if a collection will act as IEnumerable or IQueryable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ienumerable, iqueryable

I have this line of code:

```
var attachments = EntityRepository<Attachment>().Entities
.Where(at => at.EntityType == EntityType.EmailTemplate)
.ToDictionary(at => at.Extension, at => at);
```

`EntityRepository<Attachment>().Entities` is of type `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<TResult>` which implements both `IQueryable<TResult>` and `IEnumerable<TResult>`.

How can I work out if it'll act as an `IEnumerable<T>` (ie. retrieve all rows from DB, then do the filtering in C#), or as an `IQueryable<T>` (convert the C# predicate to a SQL query and retrieve only those rows).

Comment: You may check if query instance implements interface: `myQuery is IQueryable`. I have a feeling that you may hit [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), so please elaborate in the question why you want to work that out.

Comment: @IlliaPopov it's not an XY problem. The code is working fine. I'm purely curious as to what's going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have a slight misunderstanding of `IEnumerable`. It simply says the class supports iteration. It does not directly affect how any data is gotten.

Additionally, `IQueryable` implements `IEnumerable`, so all `IQueryable` instances are also `IEnumerable`. This makes sense because you can iterate over the result.

In your example, it would be the lack of `IQueryable` that means "retrieve all rows from DB, then do the filtering in C#".

Comment: That makes sense, seems obvious now! Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different extensions in LINQ - for [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netframework-4.8) and for [IQueryable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=netframework-4.8).

When you write `EntityRepository<Attachment>().Entities
.Where(at => at.EntityType == EntityType.EmailTemplate)` compiler checks the type of `Entities` and as it declares 'more specific' `IQueryable` compiler selects `Queryable.Where()` method and expression is translated by [IQueryProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable.provider?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_IQueryable_Provider) to SQL. When you write `.ToDictionary(at => at.Extension, at => at)` compiler does not find `Queryable.ToDictionary()` so it falls back to `Enumerable.ToDictionary()` and items are filtered in memory.

Rules of extension method invocation are defined in [C# language spec](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#compile-time-checking-of-dynamic-overload-resolution):

> - The set of candidate methods is reduced to contain only methods **from the most derived types**: For each method `C.F` in the set, where `C` is the type in which the method `F` is declared, all methods declared in a base type of `C` are removed from the set. Furthermore, if `C` is a class type other than `object`, all methods declared in an interface type are removed from the set. (This latter rule only has affect when the method group was the result of a member lookup on a type parameter having an effective base class other than object and a non-empty effective interface set.)

```
    public interface IInterfaceA { }
    public interface IInterfaceB : IInterfaceA { }

    public static class MyExtensions {
        public static void Print(this IInterfaceA a) => Console.WriteLine("A");
        public static void Print(this IInterfaceB b) => Console.WriteLine("B");
    }

    public class AB: IInterfaceA, IInterfaceB { }
    public class BA: IInterfaceB, IInterfaceA { }

    public partial class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new AB().Print(); // B
            new BA().Print(); // B
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for showing that it doesn't matter what order you implement the interfaces, that is a common misconception.